# This is json file named as 'abc' . I want to access file after that i want to access values of a,b,c,d,e,f . How can I access in groovy language?

Tags: json, groovy

{
"Product": [{
"a": "e3ae148d8bc2c5fe366c38da"
},
{
"b": "d211c6e7ed5bd8b4e9316a74085"
},
{
"c": "74be4f1b3b0fa5af77287780"
},
{
"d": "89856f4f139a84c98fb98b8b39c32e2"
},
{
"e": "7bd784e7d3b8490ed614345989a5"
},
{
"f": "d169f6a4a932841b12bdf8ccded57"
}
]
}

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: def data = readFile(file: 'abc.json')

println(data)

cmt_hash = data['Product']

for (k in cmt_hash)

println k

for (key in k)

NEW_COMMIT_HASH = k[key]

println "NEW_COMMIT_HASH"

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414609/this-is-json-file-named-as-abc-i-want-to-access-file-after-that-i-want-to-ac?noredirect=1#comment119276126_67414609) your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html),

```
File file = new File('abc')
String fileContent = file.text
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper() 
def result = slurper.parseText(fileContent)

println result.Product[0].a //etc.
...
```